# How to remove path and get the filename in rust?

Tags: string, rust

I have a Vector that has set of file paths that gets list of mp3 files.what i need to do is remove the path and get the filename from the each of the vector item so if i have `/home/user/Downloads/filename.ext` the extracted string should be `filename.ext` how can i implement in rust?

Comment: If you have a `Path` use [file_name()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.file_name) and if you have a `String` use [rfind](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.rfind) to find the last `/` and then extract the filename.

Comment: @Andrew or convert the `String` to a `Path`, that's probably more robust

Comment: Also, @davMe, please provide more detail. Andrew's assumptions show that your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try this ([`std::path::Path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html) utility in the standard library)

```
use std::path::Path;

let path = Path::new("my_folder/file.txt");
let filename = path.file_name().unwrap();

println!("{}", filename.to_str().unwrap());
```

Comment: Missing rust crate for us newbies :)

Comment: Oh, yes. Don't forget `use std::path::Path;` to import the crate. Cheers.